# Sent XML data to the server with Post method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send xml data to the web server,  but when I sending the data I get error ,,System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.",.

here is my code:

```
 public string postXMLData(string soap_action, string requestXml)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://secure.yieldplanet.com/XmlServices/ChannelManager.asmx");
        request.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction:XmlServices/" + soap_action);
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
        request.Accept = "text/xml";
        request.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
            return responseStr;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSDzx.png)

Comment: Error message is pretty clear: something happened on the server side. If you have access to the source code of the `ChannelManager` then check, there

Comment: Yes but I don't have access  on the ChannelManager:

Comment: As error message said - some exception have been thrown on server side. Without documentation of service or access to the source code the reason of the exception can be anything